# Extract substring: knowing the starting characters and form

Tags: string-manipulation

I'm trying to extract a specific part of a long string, where the part of interest starts with `"testx"` and ends with a number before an underscore follows, so e.g., `"abcd_xt_testx1_"` or `"abtt_xp_testx20_"` and a successful extraction would look like `"testx1"` and `testx20` respectively.

I have tried both using `StringSplit` with `"_"` as spliter, and alternatively also used `StringTake` but since I don't know whether it's a 1 digit or 2 digit number that follows `"testx"` I don't lnow how to enforce the extraction. For instance, if `test = "abcd_xt_testx1_"` then `StringTake[test, StringPosition[test,"testx"][[1]]]` would yield only `"testx"` without the number after it (here `1`).

- How can I correctly extract such substrings without a priori knowing how many digits the number that is attached to `"testx"` contains?

Comment: @march oh surprisingly complicated and neat! Thanks. Would you kindly simply copy paste it as an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
StringCases[stringExpression, "testx" ~~ Longest[DigitCharacter ..]]
```